# Rings with partial addition and their partial modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question

Earlier today I was thinking about the [Hilbert cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_cube) and how it's almost like a topological vector space.

If we think of $[0, 1]$ as being kind of like a ring except that addition is partial, then the Hilbert cube is a lot like a partial module with $[0, 1]$ as its partial ring of scalars and scalar multiplication proceeding componentwise. Let's call this partial module $H$.

I'm pretty sure that the finitely-generated submodules of $H$ are the finitely-generated subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ intersected with $[0,1]^\omega$.

I suspect that we can *break apart and rearrange* finite sums in $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ to avoid the edges of $[0,1]^\omega$; although I don't have a proof at the moment.

**Is there a theory of rings with partial addition operators and partial modules?**

Comment: It seems like this guy has worked on this stuff and has a few papers related to it: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268723319_Categories_of_generalized_rings_associated_with_partial_mappings